# Passing Map or Class to widget is better practice?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code, I have the Step class:

```dart
class Step{
  String name;
  bool completed; 

  Step({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.completed
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    'name': name,
    'completed': completed 
  };
}
```

I use Firebase as my backend and pull data from cloud firestore using StreamBuilder and pass it to my StepView widget:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
 stream: Firestore.instance.collection('step').snapshots,
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
   sample_step = snapshot.data.documents[0].data;
   return StepView(
    step: sample_step
  )
 }
)
```

My question is: What is the better practice between two options:

- Passing the raw data I pulled from cloud Firestone, which is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, to my widget:

```dart
class StepView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> step;
}
```

- Or converting the Map to the Step class and pass that instance of Step class to my widget:

```
// Convert the Map<String, dynamic> sample_test to class Step
// Need to code the method fromMapToClass in Step class
new_step = Step.fromMapToClass(sample_step) 
   return StepView(
    step: new_step
  )

class StepView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Step step;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on how you prefer to code your widgets and which state management scheme you would use. 
If I was at your place and I used ProviderModel or any other model for state management:

I would **CONVERT** the map to class object **FIRST**

You need to **implement** a method **fromMapToClass** in your class to be able to convert the firestore data to the required Step class object.
Your Step class should look somthing like this (the  function could change depending upon you data)

```
class Step {
  String name;
  bool completed;

  Step({@required this.name, @required this.completed});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'name': name, 'completed': completed};

  Step.fromMapToClass(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.name = json['name']??"";
    this.completed = json['completed']??false;
  }
}
```

**Then send the Step class object to my Widget Class**  (or StateManagement class which in ProviderModel case will be the Provider class that extends ChangeNotifier).
This way your widget will not have to handle the conversion part and can just focus on the design and implementation.

Comment: I don't use Provider and I didn't have to do any conversion part in my widget. In both case, I just need to pass a Map<String, dynamic> or a Step class to my widget and display information to the screen.



I just wonder what is the best practice, since I thought passing Map<String, dynamic> (raw data from Firestore,) doesn't require an extra method for converting, but converting to Step class creates a more readable code.

Comment: by conversion in widget class i meant that one line only. but as i said if i were you i'ld do like this. 
both of them will result same and no time difference will be there if u are wondering so u can go with whatever way u seem fit as i said as per your coding style. 
i always prefer sending very specific data in the widgets which is a common good practice to keep the code readable and simple :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I need to implement one more method in Step, fromMapToClass() :)). But it seems that you are right, it based on the coding style :))

Comment: no issues. 
and yes you need to implement that function in your class too 
i'll edit my ans and add it there too
If the answer helped u, or if u think it solved ur query u can let the community know by either verifying it or upvoting it. 
if it didnt answer ur question u can leave it as it is and i am sure someone might give a better answer to that 
Happy coding :)